# Как разбивать XML файл

Tags: wordpress, xml

У меня есть XML файл для Wordpress Import-a но немного файл большой как можно разбивать 4-5 раз чтобы меньше стала и по частям

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разбейте файл вручную на части, оставляя в каждой части общее начало и конец. Удаляйте часть файла в виде `<item> текст </item>`

Используйте программу [The WXR File Splitter v1.52](http://www.rangerpretzel.com/content/view/20/1/)

Для экспорта и импорта есть плагины. Например WP All Export, WP All Import.

[Полезная информация](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/113055/import-wordpress-xml-file-larger-than-8mb)